# How should food-difference tag be used?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Recently I tagged my [question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20958/8305) about the difference between soup and stew and I used the tag food-differences. As you can see in the edit, that tag was removed. I then went into the tag to see if there was a tag wiki and there wasn't. So I was wondering if someone can clear up exactly how this tag should be used, or rather, why I used it improperly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a [meta tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) that was once officiously slapped on a bunch of questions at the same time by an ex-member. At the time, there was a mess of hundreds of bad tags to clean up, so we didn't get around to all of them; this was one of the lower-priority ones.

There is no appropriate use of this tag. Please don't use it. The last instance of its use was over a year ago; if you see it on any questions on the front page, please remove it.

As a general rule of thumb and suggestion for all readers: Tags are intended to identify a particular area of expertise or specialization, i.e. a specific technique, food, cuisine, etc. If you can't look at a tag and honestly say "somebody's probably written a book about this" then it shouldn't exist as a tag.

(This goes for other meta tags as well like [comparisons], [classification], [hot], etc., many of which are still unfortunately in our system.)